# How can I use XmlWriter in order to create hierarchical trees dynamically?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlwriter

I need to write to a memory stream of type `Stream` some XML content. (Not a file)
I would like to know how can I use `XmlWriter` or other known classes in order to create xml hierarchical tree with lets say some recursive function.

I want to be able to write child xml tags of other parental tags etc.

I've seen something like this in the following link, but not sure this is the way, and these are Hardcoded examples.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx

Comment: Do you really *need* to use `XmlWriter`? It would be simpler to create it in memory with LINQ to XML, then write it afterwards. Are you creating a very large hierarchy?

Comment: Hi Jon, I am trying to implement some kind of xml serialization by myself(as apart of an exercise) so I want to create XML string which represent my class name , type and fields and then to write it to the `Stream`.

Comment: As Jon said, LINQ to XML would be easier.

Comment: As you know some fields can be also class instances by themself so I need a recursion to drill down each one of them in order to build XML representation of a given object